# JavaFX CSS checkbox styling

Tags: checkbox, javafx

I have some JavaFX checkboxes and want to style labels that I've assigned to them. I've put this in my .css file, but it doesn't change anything:

```
.check-box .label {
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that when you say you've "assigned labels to the check boxes" you mean that you've set text on them (either `CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox("Check this");` or `cbox.setText("Check this");`, then you just need to omit the `.label` from the css:

```
.check-box {
    -fx-font-size: 18;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Apparently, the time I've used it without ".label", I was failing cause I used ".CheckBox" :D